# With "or" in regex express can not get capture group

Tags: javascript, java, regex

The example bellow,

```
    @Test
    public void test10() {
        String str = "idcard=123433198901192, phone=12338219201";
        String regex = "(\\d{4})(\\d{7})(\\d{4})";
        //String regex = "(\\d{4})(\\d{10})(\\d{4})|(\\d{4})(\\d{7})(\\d{4})";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("full match:"+matcher.group());
            System.out.println("1 group capture:"+matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("2 group capture:"+matcher.group(2));
            System.out.println("3 group capture:"+matcher.group(3));
        }
    }
```

when i use `"(\\d{4})(\\d{7})(\\d{4})"`, both `matcher.group(1)/matcher.group(2)/matcher.group(3)/` can return capture result

```
full match:123433198901192
1 group capture:1234
2 group capture:3319890
3 group capture:1192
```

but when i use regex `"(\\d{4})(\\d{10})(\\d{4})|(\\d{4})(\\d{7})(\\d{4})"`, it cannot get the capture group result

```
full match:123433198901192
1 group capture:null
2 group capture:null
3 group capture:null
```

I guess the reason is the `or` `(|)` symbol, but i don't know why,thanks all.

Comment: There are 6 capture groups, the values are in group 4, 5 and 6

Comment: With a regex like `(a)(b)|(c)` there are 3 groups: group 1 is `(a)`, group 2 is `(b)` and group 3 is `(c)`. The numbers do **not** restart with the or. Think about it: how would you treat cases like `((a)(b)|(c))(d)` depending on the match `(d)` would be either group number 3 or group number 2... so while resetting the numbering seems to make sense in the simplest cases, it actually creates a lot of issues in more complex ones.

Comment: Why don't you use something like `(\d{4})(\d{10}|\d{7})(\d{4})`?

Comment: @Thomas yes, it seems better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to `4,7,4` or `4,10,4` **consume first the higher *length*** `10`:

```
(\d{4})(\d{10}|\d{7})(\d{4})
```

[Regex101.com sample](https://regex101.com/r/kA7PxS/3)